# What's the difference between using ::before & ::after vs hard coding the image in the HTML?

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to create this web design with a gradient svg background (red) and another svg on top of the background (blue)

[image]

So what I want to know is what's the difference between hard coding the svgs directly into the html vs using ::before & ::after

Here's the first example using ::before & ::after

```
            <div class="container">
                <nav>
                    <div class="navbar-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
```

CSS for example 1 for the blue and red svg

```
                .container:before {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    background: url(red.svg) no-repeat;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-width: 60%;
                    top: 0%;
                    right: -5%;
                }

                .container:after {
                    content: '';
                    display: block;
                    position: absolute;
                    background: url(blue.svg) no-repeat;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    max-width: 50%;
                    top: 20%;
                    right: -10%;
                    transform: rotate(-20deg);
                }
```

Now here's the way of hard coding it into the html

```
            <div class="container">
                <img src="red.svg" alt="">
                <nav>
                    <div class="navbar-menu">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <img src="blue.svg" alt="">
            </div>
```

Then for the CSS I'd just target them the same way by adding a class to each img

So I'm wondering what's the proper way to implement this style of design?

Comment: In this case it would make sense to use  ::before & ::after and not to pollute your HTML with extra tags, because it is just a presentational elements. It you would like to make some images/svgs accessible and focusable then it would be better to use actual HTML tags.

Comment: This is a borderline "opinion" question - clearly @EdvardsNiedre and I see it differently. A lot of HTML is "presentational" rather than semantic and I personally think content stuck into CSS is a last resort for stuff you can't do gracefully in HTML. But there is no right answer here.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using ::before and ::after to replace standard HTML, which is more or less what you are doing here. I'd say the main purpose of those pseudo selectors is to hack the styling for certain *repeating* elements, where normal CSS won't do the trick. A good example is pretty checkboxes. In some CSS frameworks, the default control is hidden away and replaced by content using ::after. But it's done that way because it's the only way to get around the limitations of the default implementation. Using it to insert display elements into a page when the same thing could easily be done in plain HTML makes your code harder to read and maintain and more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: ah okay. Do you know of any resources or tutorials showing how to code a website with svg images as the design? One of the example sites I'm trying to replicate is https://clickup.com/ and the way they coded it was using ::before so I wasn't sure how else to implement this design

Comment: <svg> is a standard HTML tag that works just like an img tag. You can style it just like an img with height, width, position and so on. So nothing special there. There can be a view gotchas with colours and things. If you hit those, you can always post another SO question.